# How to Align Images Side by Side with Anchor Text?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, alignment

I want to align two images side by side with anchor text below images. I need CSS code. Please Help. Please also check below Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code. This is not a free code writing service...

Comment: take a look at <figure> + <figcaption> and drop here the codes you tried, so we can help ... to hire someone do this job is not the place really :)

Comment: I was trying to use <figure> Code but it was not working. As a New Member I am not able to attach screen shot here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.left, .right {display:inline-block;}
div>a{display:block;}
```

There are so many ways to do this, here is the simplest one, link to codepen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/KzQPBm